# How can I keep my TikZ overlay picture on the same page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, page-breaking

I needed to draw squares to highlight submatrices and I found on the internet (perhaps here) a snippet that uses TikZ. By the way I found that if the math expression is at the end of the page, the square is drawn in the next page. Please compile the following code with `pdflatex` to understand what I mean. If you remove an 'a' paragraph, you get the correct behavior.

How do I solve the problem? Are there better solutions?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,intersections,shapes.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\node(#1){};}
\newcommand{\DrawBox}[1][]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
    \draw[#1]
      ($(left)+(-0.5em,1.2em)$) rectangle
      ($(right)+(0.5em,-0.5em)$);}
}

\begin{document}

    \blindtext[3]

    a

    a

    a

    a

    a

    a

    a

        \[
        J(\psi \circ \phi^{-1})\big|_{\phi(q)} = \left(
        \begin{array}{cccc}
            \tikzmark{left}\pder{y^1}{x^1} & \ldots &\pder{y^1}{x^{n-1}} &\pder{y^1}{x^{n}} \\
            \vdots & &\vdots &\vdots \\
            \pder{y^{n-1}}{x^1} &\ldots &\pder{y^{n-1}}{x^{n-1}}\tikzmark{right} &\pder{y^{n-1}}{x^n} \\
            0 &\ldots &0 & \pder{y^n}{x^n} \\
        \end{array}\right) \phi(q)
        \]
        \DrawBox[dashed]

        \blindtext[6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I compiled twice but I don't see any effect (unless I miss some pdflatex arguments). And the picture being shifted is the problem that I want to solve

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you might be experimenting with the array of `a`s is filling up a page until TeX decides the page is full and ships it out as if you have written a code like

```
....
a

a

\[
math formula contents
\] 
\newpage %<============ 
\DrawBox[dashed]

...
```

So you are providing the relative positions via `\tikzmark`s and they are recorded to the `.aux` file with respect to the **current page**(!). In the next run they are read from the `.aux` file. But since the snippet you are using is not page number aware, it's now pushed after a newpage and automatically places itself on the new page.

When you put the `\DrawBox[dashed]` command inside the display math, roughly speaking, it is considered to be a standalone item as it is placed within a page as it is and in case it doesn't fit, pushed to the new page. But `\DrawBox` will always be executed on the same page the formula is placed.

Long story short, move the `\DrawBox[dashed]` command inside the display math as the last item.

```
    \[
    J(\psi \circ \phi^{-1})\big|_{\phi(q)} = \left(
    \begin{array}{cccc}
        \tikzmark{left}\pder{y^1}{x^1} & \ldots &\pder{y^1}{x^{n-1}} &\pder{y^1}{x^{n}} \\
        \vdots & &\vdots &\vdots \\
        \pder{y^{n-1}}{x^1} &\ldots &\pder{y^{n-1}}{x^{n-1}}\tikzmark{right}%
            &\pder{y^{n-1}}{x^n} \\
        0 &\ldots &0 & \pder{y^n}{x^n} \\
    \end{array}\right) \phi(q)
    \DrawBox[dashed]
    \]
```

Comment: I actually found this solution by myself, but you gave a great explanation of the situation! Thank you very much!