# How to span brackets on some rows in longtable?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, longtable, brackets, auxiliary-files

The **goal** is to place a brackets into the table (`longtable`) to embrace some rows of this table:
[image]

The solution which involves `rdelim` and `\multirows` command (described here: [usage of `\rdelim`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164546/rotate-text-next-to-right-brace-in-multirow-environment)) gives not uniform bracket widths as well as not uniform bracket line widths while distinct brackets have various span: [`\rdelim` example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129661/how-can-i-put-some-white-space-between-consecutive-bigdelim-braces-in-tabular-w)

So the natural solution of the problem is usage of putting "remembered pictures" into the table and spanning brackets that are "decorations": [decorations in `\longtable`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79121/tikz-how-to-overlay-decorations-over-longtable)

But the **problem** is that the nodes can travel to the next page:
[image]
[image]

What to do, to prevent nodes against escaping to the next page?

The solution given for mathematical formulas ([forcing nodes to not travel to the next page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101758/how-can-i-keep-my-tikz-overlay-picture-on-the-same-page)) does not work here.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{3cm}p{3cm}}
    \toprule
    first column & second column\tikz [remember picture] \node (rightmark) {};\\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    B & B \tikz [remember picture] \node (n1) {};\\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \tikz [remember picture] \node (n2) {};\\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
% curly brace
\tikz [overlay,remember picture]
      \draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=2mm},decorate,thick]
      (n1.north -| rightmark) -- (n2.south -| rightmark)
      node [midway,right=4mm,align=left] {The bracket\\spanned on\\some rows};
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text) or [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12391/large-braces-over-several-items-in-an-itemize-with-text-by-the-brace) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution given in the question you linked ([How can I keep my TikZ overlay picture on the same page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101758/how-can-i-keep-my-tikz-overlay-picture-on-the-same-page)) **does work** here, in the following sense:

```
\begin{longtable}{p{3cm}p{3cm}}
    \toprule
    first column & second column\tikz [remember picture] \node (rightmark) {};\\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    A & A \\
    B & B \tikz [remember picture] \node (n1) {};\\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \\*
    B & B \tikz [remember picture] \node (n2) {};%
    \tikz [overlay,remember picture]
      \draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=2mm},decorate,thick]
      (n1.north -| rightmark) -- (n2.south -| rightmark)
      node [midway,right=4mm,align=left] {The bracket\\spanned on\\some rows};\\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    C & C \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}%
```

[image: output]

Note the `%` after the draw command; otherwise the first entry C will be shifted to the right.
Clearly, this solution only works as long as both nodes are on the same page.

Otherwise, you would have to look at the answer of the question [Tikz - How to overlay Decorations over longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79121/tikz-how-to-overlay-decorations-over-longtable) that you linked already.

Comment: Thx. I released that your solution is reliable in all cases only if  `\\\` command is after tikz-picture with bracket (not immediately before).

Comment: You mean the last `\tikz` should be moved before the `\\` so that two `\tikz` commands follow right after each other?  What is the problem with the current setup?

Comment: Yes. In my source file some commands are between these two `\tikz` commands (but I think it is not important here).
If the bracket have to reach the last line of the page (rows with "B" ends at the last row and rows with "C" begins at the top line of the next page) the bracket still escape to the next page (while \\ is not after the second `\tikz` but after previous one).

Comment: I edited my answer correspondingly.

Comment: OK - afrer this change is ok. Thx.

Comment: After compilation of your code it occurred that no %-sign is needed (you didn't move it together with \\-command) - there is no unwanted indent in the next table row.

Comment: Yes, because there is a `\\` right after the `\tikz`.  No need to have a `%` after a `\\`.  But I added a `%` after the first `\tikz`, just to be sure.  I did not test whether it is needed, but it does not hurt to have it.